# Copying data to a .txt, but making it look nice?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is probably horribly sloppy, but here it is! This is a section from a large (imo) GUI program I am making. The below code is what triggers when a specific button is pressed.

```
 def calc_platenumber(self):
    customer_firstname = str(self.customer2_entry.get())
    customer_lastname = str(self.customer3_entry.get())

    infile = open('license_numbers.txt', 'r')

    license_numbers = infile.readlines()

    infile.close()

    self.platenmb = random.choice(license_numbers)

    self.platenumber.set(self.platenmb)

    license_numbers.remove(self.platenmb)

    outfile = open('license_numbers.txt', 'w')

    for item in license_numbers:
        outfile.write(item)

    outfile.close()

    infile = open('used_license_numbers.txt', 'r')
    used_license_numbers = infile.readlines()
    infile.close()

    used_license_numbers.append(self.platenmb)
    used_license_numbers.append(customer_firstname)
    used_license_numbers.append(customer_lastname)

    outfile = open('used_license_numbers.txt', 'w')

    for item in used_license_numbers:
        outfile.write(item)

    outfile.close()
```

So, I have a GUI that asks for the first name and last name of the person. There is a generate button below that. The generate button will take a random license number from a large list of available numbers, remove it from that list, and then add it to a list of "used" license numbers. That is the function you see here. When it adds it to this second list, I want it to also take their name and add it as well. I have made it do that.

Problem is, whenever it adds it, it looks sloppy. No spaces or anything. I would rather it add on like...

```
Tim Bob C565213
```

And then whenever the next person uses the program, the file is updated to say...

```
Tim Bob C565213
Jim Bean 1234F324
```

...And so on. Currently it just looks sloppy, and even if sloppy won't matter (this is just a school project), it is going to bother me.

Comment: Clean code is good just for the habit of writing clean code.

Answer (score 5):

You could do a better job describing the task; the task description should be a docstring.  I would also rename the function to `select_platenumber()`, since it's not really calculating anything.

If you're using plain text files as a database, watch out for race conditions.  Unless you implement some kind of locking mechanism, you could easily end up with corrupted files.

As @JamesKhoury says, you should only have to open each file once, using a `with` block.  Use the appropriate mode: you only need to append to the output file.  For the input file, you can truncate and overwrite it.

For efficiency, I prefer to select a random array index rather than a random array element.  Selecting a random element is more readable, but to remove that element involves a linear search through the list.

I think it would be safer to write the `used_license_numbers.txt` entry before overwriting `license_numbers.txt`, in case of an I/O error.  (You could have inconsistent data, but at least you would be less likely to *lose* data.)

Having similarly variables `self.platenmb` and `self.platenumber` is confusing.

```
def select_platenumber(self):
    """Selects and removes a random line from license_numbers.txt as the
       license plate, and appends a line to used_license_numbers.txt
       recording the license plate and customer name.
    """
    firstname = str(self.customer2_entry.get())
    lastname = str(self.customer3_entry.get())

    with open('license_numbers.txt', 'r+') as in_file, \
         open('used_license_numbers.txt', 'a') as out_file:
        plates = in_file.readlines()
        self.platenmb = plates.pop(random.randrange(len(plates))).rstrip()
        self.platenumber.set(self.platenmb)

        out_file.write('%-19s %s %s\n' % (plate, firstname, lastname))

        in_file.truncate(0)
        in_file.writelines(plates)
```

Comment: If you don't want to use the format strings, you can also use the string functions ljust, rjust and center to pad you coluns in the output http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Answer (score 4):

You're opening the files more than once like:

```
infile = open('used_license_numbers.txt', 'r')
used_license_numbers = infile.readlines()
infile.close()
```

Instead write it like this:

```
with open('used_license_numbers.txt', 'r') as infile:
    used_license_numbers = infile.readlines()
```

*(python 2.6 +)*

Also you're opening the same file twice, once for reading and once for writing. Could you open it for both reading and writing?

```
open('used_license_numbers.txt', 'r+')
```